# Android and Socket.io , send and receive data

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, socket.io

I can send data to server.js and it work well but i can't receive data from server.When i click button server.js gets data i think Server.js send data but my App need some code to get data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjCHT.png)

My server.js work well

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('one user connected '+socket.id);



    socket.on('CHAT' , function (data) {
        console.log('======CHAT message========== ');
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('CHAT',data);

    });

    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log('one user disconnected '+socket.id);
    });

})

http.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('server listening on port 3000');
})
```

And my Activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Button button;
    public TextView text;
    public EditText edit;
    private io.socket.client.Socket mSocket;

    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.4:3000");


        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.d("myTag", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        text =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        edit =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        mSocket.connect();
        text.setText("");

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String message = edit.getText().toString().trim();
                edit.setText("");
                if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                    //send message
                    String jsonString = "{message: " + "'" + message + "'" + "}";

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                        mSocket.emit("CHAT", jsonData);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("me", "error send message " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });//button.setOnClickListener

    }//on create
}//end of class
```

This code need something like this to get data from Server.js , i do not know how can i use it

```
mSocket.on("CHAT", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                try {
                    JSONObject messageJson = new JSONObject(args[0].toString());
                    String message = messageJson.getString("message");
                    text.setText(message);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //  mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your toast message.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is the problem? that's how you receive that. I'm not seeing anything wrong with your code.

Comment: brother Marcos i cant receive data from server.js . i can send data from android to server.js but i cant get anything from server.js

Comment: "I can't receive" doesn't cut it. Do you get any error? where do you have your `mSocket.on("CHAT"`

Comment: https://github.com/nghianvbsc/chat_socket_on_android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/cf/bscenter/demochatsocketandroid/MainActivity.java
i have changed this link

Comment: Have you try placing a log inside `mSocket.on("CHAT")` listener? and see if it reaches there?

Comment: dear it need something like Listener that always listen port to receive data. but i dont know how can i do that.when i use **mSocket.on("CHAT")** my app dosent any error .but cant Listen port to get data

Comment: If you can emit, you can receive.

Comment: i try again . and report it

Comment: @marcos-casagrande i could solve it . thanks dear for your hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code work well. it is a real simple code to send and receive data between nodejs and android.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    public Button button;
    public TextView text;
    public EditText edit;
    public String message;
    private io.socket.client.Socket mSocket;

    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.4:3000");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.d("myTag", e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        text =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        edit =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        mSocket.connect();
        text.setText("");
        setListening();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String message = edit.getText().toString().trim();
                edit.setText("");
                if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                    //send message
                    String jsonString = "{message: " + "'" + message + "'" + "}";

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                        mSocket.emit("CHAT", jsonData);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("me", "error send message " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }//on create
        private void setListening() {
            mSocket.on("CHAT", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject messageJson = new JSONObject(args[0].toString());
                         message = messageJson.getString("message");
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                text.setText(message);
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

}//end of class
```

Comment: Hey @Moh_beh When I disconnect the socket and reopen main activity and then try to get message using setListening() that method call multiple time. I got the same object multiple time.
Can you help me?

Comment: hey @Moh_ben I tried the exact same code but for localhost and the app running from an emulator and it doesn't work. Do you know what could be the reason? Greetings

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps is late but you have a mistake in your code.

```
socket.on('CHAT' , function (data) {
    console.log('======CHAT message========== ');
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('CHAT',data);

});

socket.off('disconnect',function(){
    console.log('one user disconnected '+socket.id);
});
```

When disconnecting, you are calling to socket.on instead socket.off. I fixed in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Check you socket version in gradle, I resolved the issue by downgrading from

2.0.0 to 0.8.3

```
implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') { 
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

and it worked for me